# Swift array of Codable is not Codable

Tags: swift, codable

Apple's documentation on `Codable` states:

> Built-in types such as `Array`, `Dictionary`, and `Optional` also conform to `Codable` whenever they contain codable types.

However, the following code snippet results in a compilation error, telling me that `Storage` does not conform to the `Codable` protocol.

```
struct Storage: Codable {
    var data: [Codable]
}
```

Why isn't this compiling?

Comment: I think that was the wrong question to consider as a duplicate. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/169346 to a different question has the complete reason for why `Array<Codable>` isn't `Codable`.

Comment: `data` must be a concrete static type, at least a generic constrained to `Codable`

Comment: Essentially, `Codable` is not a type, it is a protocol. `Array<X> where X: Codable` would work because `X` is a type even if it is generic. In particular it only has one possibility for `init(from:)` for the compiler to choose from

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Your linked answer indeed provides an explanation for my case.